# How does the equal sign relate to the arrow function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I recently started with ES6, and I understood the use of arrow functions, such as:

```
const divisibleByThrreeES6 = array.filter(v => v % 3 === 0);
```

However, I found [this](https://github.com/alwinn1977/react-simple-flowchart/blob/master/src/index.js) library where the following line is written:

```
<div ref={div => this.chart = div}/>
```

I am wondering about the part in curly braces. I assume that the function is:

```
function(div) {
    return this.chart;
}
```

Is that correct? What does the equal sign `= div` have to do with it? I could not find documentation explaining that last part.

Comment: No, it's `function(div) {
    return this.chart = div;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume that the function is

It isn't.

It is:

```
function(div) {
    return this.chart = div;
}.bind(this)
```

It assigns the value of `div` to `this.chart` and then returns that value from the function.

Odds are that the return value is never used, and it is only being returned as a side effect of using the single expression arrow function syntax.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for.